# Truncate list items

Tags: python, list, truncate

Say there is a list

```
["element1 abc, 1999 mno", "element2 abc", "element3 xyz, 2019 pqr", "element4 xyz", "element5 xyz, 1999 wasd"]
```

I want to truncate all the items of the list if a pattern is present.
Lets say the pattern is `["xyz, \d{4}", "abc, \d{4}"]`
The resultant list would be

```
["element1 abc, 1999", "element2 abc", "element3 xyz, 2019", "element4 xyz", "element5 xyz, 1999"]
```

Items at position 0, 2 and 4 were truncated because pattern `"xyz,"+year` and `"abc,"+year` were encountered.

Below is my current code

```
import re

ls = ["element1 abc, 1999 mno", "element2 abc", "element3 xyz, 2019 pqr", "element4 xyz", "element5 xyz, 1999 wasd"]
outls = []
pattern = ["xyz, \d{4}", "abc, \d{4}"]

for i in ls:
    appendTracker = 1
    for j in pattern:
        match = re.search(j, i)
        if match:
            matched = match.group()
            appendTracker = 0
            outls.append(i[:i.rfind(matched)+len(matched)])
            break
        
    if appendTracker:
        outls.append(i)
```

Is there a better way to do this. Time is not big of an issue but I do want to reduce lines of code

Comment: Please edit your code attempting to solve this problem into your question. (StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service)

Comment: You can use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) regular expressions module to match patterns in text strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your pattern has a fixed length, the words following the pattern can be found by [positive lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=lookbehind) `(?<=)`.

**Code**

```
ls = ["element1 abc", "element2 abc", "element3 xyz, 2019 pqr", "element4 xyz", "element5 xyz, 1999 wasd"]    
ans = [re.sub(r"(?<=(xyz|abc)\, \d{4}).*", "", s) for s in ls]
```

**Output**

```
print(ans)

['element1 abc',
 'element2 abc',
 'element3 xyz, 2019',
 'element4 xyz',
 'element5 xyz, 1999']
```

Comment: What if the patterns are variable. For eg. if pattern had one more item: ["xyz, \d{4}", "abc, \d{4}", "proc, wa"]. How would you modify the code?

Comment: I tried and was able to achieve this with: ans1 = [re.sub(r"(?<=(xyz, \d{4}|abc, \d{4})).*", "", s) for s in ls]. But when I substitute it with join function, it gives a syntax error. ans2 = [re.sub((?<=("|".join(pattern))), "", s) for s in ls]

Comment: Got it. [re.sub(r"(?<=(" + "|".join(pattern) + ")).*", "", s) for s in ls]